# Formatting MYSQL call in PHP to TRIM

Tags: php, mysql, syntax, quotes, trim

I am having difficulty running the following command in PHP:

```
$con = mysql_connect("host", "username", "password") or die ("Unable to connect to server");
mysql_select_db("database") or die ("Unable to select database");
$sql = "UPDATE `table` SET `column` = TRIM(BOTH '"' FROM `column`)";
mysql_query($sql);
echo "quotation mark removed";
mysql_close($con);
```

The issue has to do with the syntax I believe.  Specifically the `BOTH '"' FROM` portion.  How can I write this $sql call so that it will be understood by PHP?

This was my attempt `BOTH '"."""."' FROM`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape double quote (since you use it as a string delimiter), like:

```
$sql = "UPDATE `table` SET `column` = TRIM(BOTH '\"' FROM `column`)";
```